# Parsing COPY...WITH BINARY results

Tags: postgresql

I'm using this:

> COPY( select field1, field2, field3 from table ) TO 'C://Program
>   Files/PostgreSql//8.4//data//output.dat' WITH BINARY

To export some fields to a file, one of them is a ByteA field. Now, I need to read the file with a custom made program.

How can I parse this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general format of a file generated by `COPY...BINARY` is explained in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN66736), and it's non-trivial.

`bytea` contents are the most easy to deal with, since they're not encoded.

Each other datatype has its own encoding rules, which are not described in the documentation but in the source code. From the doc:

> To determine the appropriate binary format for the actual tuple data
>   you should consult the PostgreSQL source, in particular the *send and
>   *recv functions for each column's data type (typically these functions are found in the src/backend/utils/adt/ directory of the source
>   distribution).

Comment: Thanks!, with the help of the documentation you pointed out, I've implemented a simple parser to read the whole file. It's simple because all of my fields where Varchar, except of one ByteA.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use the text format rather than binary (so just remove the `WITH BINARY`).  The text format has better documentation and is designed for better interoperability.   The binary format is more intended for moving between postgres installations, and even there they have version incompatibilities.

Text format will write the bytea field as if it was text, and encode any non-printable characters with `\nnn` octal representation (except for a few special cases that it encodes with C style `\x` patterns, such as `\n` and `\t` etc.)  These are listed in the [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) documentation.

The only caveat with this is you need to be absolutely sure that the character encoding you're using is the same when saving the file as when reading it.  To make sure that the printable characters map to the same numbers.  I'd stick to SQL_ASCII as it keeps thing simpler.